# How to distribute rules?

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

For example i want to have following equation :

```
Det[A B C]=Det[A] Det[B] Det[C]
```

What is the simplest way to distribute automatically?

Comment: Are you aware that you need `.` for multiplication of matrices?

Comment: @gwr yes just did not want it to look like ABC as one matrix. basically A.B.C

Comment: `Det /@ # & @@ Det[A.B.C]` gives `Det[A].Det[B].Det[C]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: or, `Distribute[Det[A.B.C], Dot]`

Comment: none fx = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
cx = Det[Transpose@fx.fx ]
Det[fx]*Det[Transpose[fx]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
det[x__Dot] := Det /@ Times @@ x;
det[x_] := Det[x];
```

Now

```
det[A . B . C] == Det[A] Det[B] Det[C]
```

returns `True`.